# Too Small Response Buffer with SpringBoot, SpringSecurity and FreeMarker views and CSRF

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, freemarker

I use SpringBoot, SpringSecurity for my application and FreeMarker to render views (used starters for both spring-security and freemarker).

I encounter an exception when rendering bigger views with CSRF tokens. These views exceeds the response buffer size and the first part of the response gets already committed before the whole view is completely rendered. If then a CSRF token should get rendered, I encounter the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:3049)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2493)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:908)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:920)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:253)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:253)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:253)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.saveToken(HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.java:58)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.LazyCsrfTokenRepository$SaveOnAccessCsrfToken.saveTokenIfNecessary(LazyCsrfTokenRepository.java:168)
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.LazyCsrfTokenRepository$SaveOnAccessCsrfToken.getToken(LazyCsrfTokenRepository.java:125)
```

Setting a bigger buffer programatically with `response.setBufferSize(..)` in a filter seems to workaround this problem, but it does not feel like a good solution. I do not want to increase the buffer for every request, nor do I want to track which endpoints render views and increase the buffer only for them. Furthermore, if a view gets bigger, the current buffer size may be too small again.

So is there a better solution, for example rendering the whole view before start writing to the writer of the response (found nothing how one could achieve this)? Or is there some configuration for spring security which allows one to get the token also after a response is committed. Or should I get the CSRF token eagerly in the controller method and pass them to the model so FreeMarker is able to render the view independent of the session?

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be surprisingly easy. I configured the CsrfTokenRepository manually and used the `HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository` directly instead of the `LazyCsrfTokenRepository` which is just a wrapper around `HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository` which allows to access the token after the response has been committed.